# Why is a value never NOT in collection with nulls?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wasn't getting any results where I expected them and long story short I found this odd behavior:

```
select 1 where 'a' in ('a', 'b', null)
 -> 1

select 1 where 'a' NOT in ('b', 'c', null)
 -> empty resultset
```

I'm relatively new to SQL Server (coming from MySQL) but this seems a bug to me, is this expected/desired behavior? I'm aware of the `anything + null == null` paradigm, but if that's the explanation, then I would expect the first query to return an empty resultset just the same.

I also tried:

```
select 1 where NOT ('a' in ('b', 'c', null))
```

again an empty resultset, I'm confused now...

I added `where [mycolumn] is not null` to my original query, problem solved, but I'm just curious.

**Edit**

I see from the duplicate marking that this depends on the setting of `ansi_nulls`. When this is *on*, `null` is treated as `unknown`. And yes I can see that you cannot say with certainty that any value is absent in a collection that has an unknown value.

Why would you want to regard `null` as `unknown` though? They are very different concepts to me.

`null` means there is no value, like asking what's in the `[gum]` drawer to someone whose cabinet doesn't have a `[gum]` drawer.
`unknown` means there IS a value, but for some reason we don't have access to that value. Maybe the `[gum]` drawer is locked, it might have content, it might be empty, but it's not `null`, it's `unknown`.

Where is my thinking off with this?

Comment: NOT IN => 'a' <> 'b' AND 'a' <> 'c' AND 'a' <> NULL => True AND True AND NULL => NULL

Comment: The behavior of NULLs is defined in the ANSI SQL standard.  I'm pretty sure MySQL and SQL Server have the same rules.

Comment: I have three people. I know the first name of one of them is `David`, the second one's name is `Tom`, and I don't yet know the name of the third person. In that set of three people, is it definitely known that *none* of them have the name `Stephanie`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're implying sql server treats `null` as `unknown`. To me, `null` means that the value is absent. Like a newborn baby without a given name yet. She might be called `Stephanie` in the future, but I'm not querying the database in the future, I'm querying RIGHT NOW. `Tom` might change his name to `Stephanie` in the future too, that doesn't mean I want the query to suggest this _might_ happen when I run it :P

Comment: The issue is that, in SQL, `null` has, at times, both some of the `unknown` nature, and some of the `inapplicable` nature (and possibly others you may be thinking of). Unfortunately, the SQL language is already pretty set in this mindset (although it's also worth pointing out that SQL actually has a concept *called* `UNKNOWN`, which is the third truth value produced when there's a `NULL` input to a predicate that can't be eliminated. so `'a' NOT in ('b', 'c', null)` actually evaluates as `UNKNOWN` (rather than `FALSE`).

Comment: If MySQL returned anything from the second statement, that is a but in **MySQL**

Comment: You might also find [Codd's Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd's_12_rules) interesting reading. Those were the basis behind the thinking for SQL. And note, again, that in this case, `null` was being considered at different times as "there is no value" and "we do not know the value". Codd later proposed alternatives that involved multiple types of `null`s, where one would be `not applicable`, one would be `not known`, etc, but SQL is insane enough with just one `null`. **You** may want `null` to only mean the (proven) absence of a value, but that's not the line that SQL took.