# Why NOT IN didn't work

Tags: mysql

Originally, I want to create a some sort of id for user, but I can't change my data table into `unique` for several reason. So I have to generate unique random data manually, so I decide to do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("B",FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999)) AS random_number
FROM mmr
WHERE "random_number" NOT IN (SELECT rm FROM mmr) LIMIT 1
```

with `FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999)` I was able to get random data between 10000-99999 but it's still not unique.

mmr is large table with more than 2M data and rm type is `varchar(12)`. The result I was expecting is `Bxxxxx`

I also tried to use `not exists` but no result came in

Comment: The `SELECT` part is only executed once. You'd have to run that query over and over again, until a `random_number` happens to be unused. Very inefficient.

Comment: Wait, so you want 2 000 000 unique numbers between 10 000 and 99 999? Some algorithm that would be **;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to refer to the value that was randomly generated in the `SELECT` part by referencing its `random_number` alias in the `WHERE` clause. No can do. As well you are possibly comparing `random_number` with a `NULL` field because of your `NOT IN` condition. This will evaluate to `NULL` (or effectively `FALSE`).

You could try:

```
SELECT random_number
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT("B",FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999)) AS random_number
    FROM mmr
) t
WHERE t.random_number NOT IN (
    SELECT rm
    FROM mmr
    WHERE rm IS NOT NULL
)
LIMIT 1
```

Now the inner query will generate as much random numbers as there are records in `mmr`, but within that query might already be duplicates. After that any numbers that were *already* in `mmr` get filtered out, leaving you with fewer random numbers than there are records in `mmr`.

(I asked about *`'B' NOT IN ('A', NULL)`* once [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018496/why-is-a-value-never-not-in-collection-with-nulls) and got some good comments explaining it)

Comment: `"random_number"` this should behave as string not variable.

Comment: @Girish doesn't change the behavior, effectively your asking _'Is column (or string) "random_number" absent in this set of values which contains an unknown value?"_ and MySQL says _'I can't know for sure, maybe the unknown value is equal to "random_number", so I'm gonna say `null`'_. Now in SQL Server `"` denotes a column-name that has special chars, I do believe in MySQL that would be the backtick ` in stead.

Comment: anyway op added mysql tag in question, if you use as variable then the query will return error `#1054 - Unknown column 'random_number' in 'where clause' ` because random_number is not table fields

Comment: also, adding `rm IS NOT NULL` still gave me non unique results

Comment: I expanded the answer substantially, but I'm wondering about the ultimate goal here. Could you not simply have ascending numbers starting from `B10000`? If you absolutely need them to be random, I think you're going to have to generate 1 unique number, insert it, generate a new number, see if it exists, if not insert it, else discard it, continue until you've generated enough random numbers that weren't discarded for existing... As well, 2 000 000 unique numbers between 10 000 and 99 999? ehhh....?

Comment: I didn't say in my question but `Bxxxxx` is only part of user, there are also `xxxxxx` and others. Some even have double id but it's not my problem. This `Bxxxxx` user already exist and the number is random, I can't get top number and add +1, since there are so many unused number. Anyway, your query is working, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("B",FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999)) AS random_number
FROM mmr
WHERE random_number NOT IN (SELECT rm FROM mmr WHERE rm IS NOT NULL)
```

EDIT: why "limit 1" was in your code? I have deleted it, not useful in this case.. it could be the cause of your issue, because it takes only one record

Comment: why we use @with field name?

Comment: because is not a field but var, I think..

i have edited my answer

Comment: you can't use defined variable in same query condition, because select condition proceed first then emerged result, according your query condition depend on query result

Comment: I use LIMIT1 because I want to generate one unique id. And thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: and if you put "..."?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` with query and check `random_number` exist in table rows

```
SELECT random_number
FROM mmr
CROSS JOIN (SELECT CONCAT("B",FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999)) AS random_number) rmt
WHERE random_number <> rm AND rm IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it give me error `SQL execution error #1064` I tried to rewrite it several ways but still no luck